# error with tf and laser_scan

Tags: ros, laser-scan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I build a navigation stack for my robot. When I roslaunch the launch file, the screen shows "error: couldn't transform from laser to base_footprint, even though the message notifier is in use". After a while, it said "error: couldn't determine robot's pose associated with laser scan". The screen images are shown below. Is there anyone know what's wrong with tf or laser_scan? Thanks very much.[image: image description][image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191925/error-with-tf-and-laser_scan/) by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-04**:
Can you write more info.

**Comment by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on 2014-09-04**:
@bvbdort, I have write the problem in detail. Do you have some suggestion about the errors?Thanks.

**Comment by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on 2014-09-04**:
ros version is hydro

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-05**:
take a loot at `rosrun tf view_frames` and post frame.pdf , it give more info on tf of your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@bvbdort, thanks. The problem is solved. I publish the transform from base_link to odom twice which caused the error.

---

Originally posted by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) with karma: 76 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-03-25**:
how did you get to know that? I'm facing the same problem

**Comment by [nilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/152534/nilesh/) on 2023-06-22**:
how did you solve this I am facing the same issue as well ?